# Query Fallback in Where Clause if Given Condition Doesn't Evaluate to True

Tags: mysql, select, duplicates

Imagine the following scenario: I have a list of Labels stored in a table and a list of languages stored in another. I have the user's current language (e.g. Arabic) and I want to query all labels from their table with the following condition:
If they exists in Arabic, get the Arabic version. If the Label doesn't exists in Arabic fallback to English and get the English version.

The issue is that it may exist in both Arabic and English and I don't want to select both rows (so simply using `WHERE label_language='arabic' OR label_language='english'` won't work) and if possible, I would like to do this in a single query.

Labels table:

```
id (non unique)|label_name|label_language
1|Something|arabic
1|Something Else|english
3|Blabla|english
4|Some text|english
4|Some other text|arabic
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT l1.id, COALESCE(l2.label_name, l1.label_name) AS label_name
    FROM Labels l1
        LEFT JOIN Labels l2
            ON l1.id = l2.id
                AND l2.label_language = 'arabic'
                AND l2.label_name <> ''
    WHERE l1.label_language = 'english'
```

Comment: A bit of explanation would be really helpful if this is not an issue.

Comment: @ColorWP.com The `l1` table returns all labels in English. The left join to `l2` looks for Arabic equivalents for each of those English labels, if they exist. The COALESCE chooses which to return; the Arabic (from `l2`) if it exists, the English (from `l1`) if it doesn't.

Comment: It's worth noting that this will not overwrite the Arabic label with the default (English) label if the Arabic label exists, but it's name is empty. In this case we should add a `l2.label_name!=''` to the `WHERE` clause of the `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @ColorWP.com: Add that test to the `LEFT JOIN`, not to the `WHERE`. I'll update my answer to reflect this.